# How to secure my login credentials within an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following situation:

I have a `Javascript` website where the user need to enter a username and a password and then the site make a ajax call to the `Webserver`.

On the other site I have a `Webserver` running `PHP` which gets the parameters and checks if the username and password is right.

**Now my Problem:**

How to secure this process e.g: how to secure it if the website does not use **https** and the user submits his username and password? Is there any algorithm which can do this?

Comment: post your php codes to know whether you have any security flaws

Comment: You can encrypt the username and password in javascript, but anyone who has access to the login page will be able to see what encryption is used, and it will be useless.

Comment: WHat is sent to server via ajax is no different than submitting a form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Even if you hash or encrypt the data in the browser before sending it, the algorithm and keys would be public, and the resulting information also can be intercepted and replicated by an attacker.

If you want it to be secure, you need to use HTTPS.